# Varying length of MD5 checksum in python

Tags: python, binary, md5, hashlib

I use the following code to compute the binary representation of MD5 hashcode.

MD5 is *always* 128 bytes, and `bin` returns a string starting with "0b". Therefore, the length of `md5_bin` must **always** be 130, but when I run the program, it varies between 128 and 130, on different values of `random_str`.

```
md5_bin = bin(int(hashlib.md5(random_str).hexdigest(),16))`
print len(md5_bin)
```

Comment: `bin` will not add leading `0`s... (how should it know how many to add?).  `len(hashlib.md5(random_bytes).hexdigest())` will always be 32.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sure, MD5 is always 128 bytes, but sometimes the first byte is a 0, and occasionally the second byte is too.

Think of it this way: the decimal string `'15'` and the decimal `'0015'` are both the same number `15`. When you ask Python to convert the `int` `15` to a string, you're going to get `'15'`, not `'0015`'. It has no way of knowing that you wanted 4 digits instead of 2:

```
>>> n = int('0015')
>>> str(n)
'15'
```

And it's the same with `bin`. It has no way of knowing that you wanted 128 bits instead of 126. You gave it a number with 126 bits, so it gives you 126 binary digits.

But you can tell it you want that, e.g., with a [format spec](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language):

```
bits = format(md5_bin, '0128b')
```

… or, equivalently:

```
bits = '{:0128b}'.format(md5_bin)
```

If you want the `0b` prefix, you can add that:

```
bits = format(md5_bin, '#0128b')
bits = '{md5_bin:#0128b}'.format(md5_bin)
bits = '0b{md5_bin:0128b}'.format(md5_bin)
```

Comment: great answer! but the question was written in python 2. you may confuse the OP with format strings...

Comment: @hiroprotagonist You're right; changed it to use `str.format`. (And updated the docs link to the Python 2 version.)